ldapsearch: ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
We have two forests - each forest has one DC i.e DC - prod.com and test.com respectively. I've set up a transitive trust between the forest. I'm able to login into the DC test.com using the username and password of DC prod.com in RDP. But I'm not able to do the ldapsearch through the same username and password of DC prod.com into DC test.com.
ldapsearch -vx -L -H ldaps://<IP of test.com>:636 -D 'admin@prod.com' -w '****' -b "DC=test,DC=com" -s sub "(cn=*)"

I'm getting this error
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
additional info: 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C09050F, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v4f7c
